# Change navigation in slide scroller

Tags: jquery, paging

I have this slide scroller, which is working fine. However, I would like to change the way the navigation looks. This is a raw example of what I have now - [see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meek/8S8cR/).

I would like to change the navigation to say "<< x out of y >>" where 'x' is the current slide and 'y' is the total number of slides.

I think all the necessary variables are there in the script - I just can't make it look and work the way I want to.

I have tried to change this line of code:

```
scrollMenu.append('<div class="' + ((i == 0) ? activeClass : '') + ' slide-button slide-index">' + i + '</div>');
```

...But I couldn't get it working.
Also, the number of slides starts with zero. I guess I need to add a +1 somewhere. I just can't see where.

Anybody wants to give a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code at the line you mentioned, you have `scrollMenuSlideItemsNum` available to you, which looks like the current page and you have `numSlides` which is the number of slides. So instead of looping through, just delete the `for` and put something like

```
"<< " + scrollMenuSlideItemsNum + " of " + numSlides + " >>"
```

But you have to change a few other things as well. You'll have to change the click handler so that it works differently when you click the different parts. You'll have to write a new class for the div you're appending. You'll have to write a function to update the new layout.

Comment: Hi brentonstrine, thanks for your input. Much appreciated. I'm afraid I'm not good enough to make this stuff. Any chance you could show me an example?

Comment: I just came across Pioul's great slider here: http://pioul.fr/jquery-diyslider/ - it does exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks for your time.

Comment: glad you found something. sorry i couldn't go more into detail, i've been a little busy. keep mucking around though, you'll get the hang of it pretty quick.